# C# form switch and vice versa

Tags: c#, winforms, fundamentals-ts

Assume that I have a C# Solution with 3 projects Main, Program1, Program2.
I want to have a "Main form", when I click on button "Program1" the main form will be hidden, Program1 will be showed, and when I close Program1, the Main form will return.
How can I do this? 
I tried add Program1 and PRogram2 as Reference to Project Main and code like below in Main, it works for call Program1, but can't handle event Program1.closed() because when I try to reference Main to Program1, it error

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
A reference to 'Main' could not be added. Adding this project as a reference would cause a circular dependency.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

I searched Google and got nothing helpful!

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Switch
{
    public partial class Main : Form
    {
        public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Program1.Form1 pf1 = new Program1.Form1();
            pf1.Show();
            this.Hide(); 
        }
    }
}
```

[image: my solution]
[image: my main form, quite simple]

Comment: Do you really want 3 different applications? Or just 1 application with 3 Forms?

Comment: thanks for quick comment @CamiloTerevinto , I need 3 applications caused it comes from 3 different vendors.

Comment: I guess you could fire up each form using `new Process` and implement single instance to bring up the other form.

Comment: @zcui93 : Main form have just been hidden, not closed, so I need to show it  back, not another Main form instance.

Comment: Yes. Search for different single instance approaches. That's what you need.

Comment: @zcui93 thanks, looks good! I will try it at 8AM tomorrow and report with an answer! (it's 2AM now at my location)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for answers!
After confirmed with customer, they don't strictly need the "mainform" to be hidden, so I came with another easier solution:
1. For the "child form", I use `ShowDiaglog()` instead of `Show()`

```
    private void btnChildForm1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var frm = new ChildForm1();
        frm.ShowDialog();
    }
```

2. For the mainform, I use `mutex` to force it to be only 1 instance:

   ```
   static class Program
   {
       /// <summary>
       /// The main entry point for the application.
       /// </summary>
       /// 


       [STAThread]
       static void Main()
       {
           var mutex = new Mutex(true, "MainForm", out var result);
           if (!result)
           {
               MessageBox.Show("Running!");
               return;
           }
           Application.EnableVisualStyles();
           Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
           Application.Run(new MainForm());
           GC.KeepAlive(mutex);
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

As zcui93 commented you can use process to make it work. You can either have all 3 in same folder (when you deploy the app on client machine)

```
using System.Diagnostics;
...
Process process = new Process();
// Configure the process using the StartInfo properties.
process.StartInfo.FileName = "process.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-n";
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();// Waits here for the process to exit.
```

In C# you can use the [Process.Exited](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited(v=vs.110).aspx) event. This event doesn't work when someone close the app when someone kill the app from task manager.

Answer (score 0):

Circular dependencies use to happen when the project arquitecture is not good.
In your case i think the problem migth be the program1 or program2 have Main as a reference.
Remove de Main reference from the program1 and program2.
The main project must have reference to the program1 and program2.

Comment: thanks for feedback, I understand the error, you missed my point. I need some way to show Main form again after Program1 closed.